# Why Guid.TryParse allows trailing/leading spaces

Tags: c#

One of our existing codes failed because a developer used Guid.TryParse to check if an input string is a valid Guid value and the input itself has a trailing space.

```
            if (Guid.TryParseExact("0c652e2a-ef02-4eff-8855-78122d8b6c0b ", "D", out var guid1))
                _logger.LogWarning("guid1");
            if (Guid.TryParse("0c652e2a-ef02-4eff-8855-78122d8b6c0b ", out var guid2))
                _logger.LogWarning("guid2");
            if (Guid.TryParse(" 0c652e2a-ef02-4eff-8855-78122d8b6c0b ", out var guid3))
                _logger.LogWarning("guid3");
            if (int.TryParse(" 1", out int int1))
                _logger.LogWarning("int1");
```

The output is

[image]

Anyone knows why is this? I would argue "0c652e2a-ef02-4eff-8855-78122d8b6c0b " is not a valid Guid because it has a trailing space.  The same argument can be made "0c652e2a-ef02-4eff-8855-78122d8b6c0 b" is also not a valid GUID.

It seems like Microsoft library tries to be smart and trim trailing/leading spaces ....

Comment: [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/guid.cs) line 378.  As to why, probably just convenience?

Comment: One could argue that "whitespace" around the GUID doesn't necessarily affect whether or not the GUID itself is valid.  The REAL question is why whitespace isn't acceptable to your app.  SUGGESTION: write your own `IsValid()` method that wraps MS `Guid.TryParse()` ... and also checks for whitespace (and anything else that might cause your app to fail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tryparse?view=net-7.0), that's how it was designed...no "Why" given.

> This method is like the Parse method, except that instead of returning
> the parsed GUID, it returns false if input is null or not in a
> recognized format, and doesn't throw an exception. **It trims any**
> **leading or trailing white space from input** and converts strings in any
> of the five formats recognized by the ToString(String) and
> ToString(String, IFormatProvider) methods, as shown in the following
> table.

(Emphasis mine)

If you'd like to get around that, you could always replace spaces with some illegal character.

Here's a snippet of the actual code running (from decompilation).  You'll notice there's no flag you can set to avoid it.

```
private static bool TryParseGuid(string g, GuidStyles flags, ref GuidResult result)
{
  if (g == null)
  {
    result.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind.Format, "Format_GuidUnrecognized");
    return false;
  }

  string text = g.Trim();
...
```